# "Specified method is not supported" error with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, itext, notsupportedexception

I'm using [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) to generate PDFs. I've added a test method below that makes a simple page with one paragraph. It works, the PDF is generated, however, sometime after the PDF is sent to the browser I get a NotSupportedException in the Event log (or if I catch them myself from Application_Error). Here's the simplest code that causes this error:

```
public FileStreamResult TestPdf()
{
  using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    using (var document = new Document())
    {
      PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);
      document.Open();
      document.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"));
      document.Close();
    }
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=test.pdf");
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.Clear();
    Response.OutputStream.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, ms.GetBuffer().Length);
    Response.OutputStream.Flush();
    Response.End();
  }
  return new FileStreamResult(Response.OutputStream, "application/pdf");
}
```

And the error it throws (sometime after the request was completed)

```
Exception information: 
Exception type: NotSupportedException 
Exception message: Specified method is not supported.
at System.Web.HttpResponseStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at System.Web.Mvc.FileStreamResult.WriteFile(HttpResponseBase response)
at System.Web.Mvc.FileResult.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19()
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__1b()
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d()
at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f)
at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Any ideas on how I could fix this? Is there a problem with the library or something else?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

To solve this problem, rather than return FileStreamResult I was able to use FileContentResult instead via the Controller's File method. Here's the working code:

```
public ActionResult TestPdf()
{
  using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    using (var document = new Document())
    {
      PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);

      document.Open();
      document.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"));
      document.Close();
    }
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=test.pdf");
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.Clear();        
    return File(ms.ToArray(), "application/pdf");
  }
}
```

Comment: i Test your code in a simple asp page and gotta no error, every thing works well!

can you show us where you call the TestPdf() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error is in this line:

```
Response.OutputStream.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, ms.GetBuffer().Length);
```

Use `ToArray` instead of `GetBuffer`. Like this:

```
var bytes = ms.ToArray();
Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

`MemoryStream.GetBuffer` returns allocated bytes, not filled bytes.

Example of the issue:

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    memoryStream.WriteByte(1);
    var length = memoryStream.ToArray().Length; // returns 1
   var bufferLength = memoryStream.GetBuffer().Length; // returns 256
}
```

Although one byte is added, `GetBuffer` will return 256 bytes.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't make the NotSupportedException exception go away, but I did incorporate your fix. Thanks.

Comment: I think you should not return `Response.OutputStream`. What if you just try to return this without disposing `ms` : `HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=form.pdf"); return new FileStreamResult(ms, "application/pdf");`.

Comment: I get a "Cannot access a closed Stream" exception. Even if I try a "ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)" before returning I get the same exception, so I assume iTextSharp document closes the stream at some point.

Comment: @pbz - did you remove `using` around memory stream?

Comment: Yes, the stream is "closed". .ToArray() works, but anything else (like Seek) doesn't.

Comment: @Alex this is probably why in the samples I found (http://ozzieperez.net/blog/?p=255) they all output to the Response.OutputStream rather than pass the stream to FileStreamResult -- just a guess

Comment: I accepted your answer because it took me half way there, thanks!

Comment: You were... I would not have thought about .ToArray() and the File method that takes a stream doesn't work as the stream is closed by iTextSharp -- I assume, so in this case you pretty much have to use the byte[] override.